# how do I access a variable outside a function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

how do I access a variable outside a function while that variable is constantly being updated in python.

I just need an example to go on from as I cannot find a relevant solution online. I have a variable that contains a download percentage/float but it is constantly being updated with a new value but I need to access it outside of the function it's in. Is this possible? How?

Comment: You encapsulate the value into a class...

Comment: Thank you, worked straight away!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can you show an example of this if possible?

Answer (score 0):

well you can try to declare it as global,
let's say this variable is called x, you can type global x inside your function
this way you can access its value from the outside.
Now i need to mention that this method has some risks because declaring it as
global means also that you can alter its value from the outside too!, and that can mess up things if you're not careful. This is why it's better to avoid the global variables as much as possible.

Comment: Yh i found a way around it without having to use global variables, I put it in the same class as the function updating the value its using and put it in its own function within the same class and it works like a gem. :) thanks for all the help guys